# Sumif & Indirect

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In using the following sumif/indirect function

(=+SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!$B$2:$B$102"),$C13,INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!F2:F102"))

my columns (F:F) wont move as I drag the formula to the right.  Is there a way I can make this dynamic and drag formula to update across columns (F > G > H, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

There may be simpler ways, but I think this will work:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!$B$2:$B$102"),$C13,INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!"&ADDRESS(2,5+COLUMNS($A:A))&":"&ADDRESS(102,5+COLUMNS($A:A))))
```

I am assuming the only part you want to make dynamic is the F2:F102

Here is another formula that should work, also.  It puts the sheetname reference inside the ADDRESS function.  I don't know if one is better than the other.

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!$B$2:$B$102"),$C13,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,5+COLUMNS($A:E),,,$A$3)&":"&ADDRESS(102,5+COLUMNS($A:E))))
```

Comment: `CELL("address", F2:F102)`

Comment: @Aprillion Not sure about that.  It is volatile; and, at least in Excel 2007, will only return $F$2 (the address of the first cell).

Comment: what is your point? `INDIRECT` is volatile already and `CELL` returns `$G$2`, `$H$2` and so on when you copy it, the dollar signs themselves are completely irrelevant in this particular case

Comment: @Aprillion One has to return `sheetname!F2:F102`, not just `F2`.  So if you did something like `("'"&$A$3&"'!"&CELL("address",F2)&":"&CELL("address",F102))` the result would be sensitive to row insertion, which the original is not.  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I see your point - @Ryan should it be sensitive to row insertion? if you add a new row between 2 and 102, should the formula update to `F2:F103`?

Comment: @Aprillion Since the original was not sensitive to row insertion, I assumed he wanted the replacement sensitive only to the column dragging.  If he didn't want to do that, why use INDIRECT at all?

Comment: to provide the sheet name

Comment: @Aprillion Yes, of course.